# Integral of asymptotic equal functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have lemma to prof about asymptotic equal functions, could you please advise me on it?

Let $h_{i}: R^{2} \to R$ for $i=1,2$ such that $h_{1} (x,y) \underset{x \to a} {\asymp} h_{2} (x,y)$ for all $y \in R$, and integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{i} (x,y) dy $ exists. 
Then:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{1}(x,y) dy \underset{x \to a} {\asymp} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{2}(x,y) dy$$

Any ideas?

Comment: If i use dominated convergence theorem, i have: $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{1}(x,y) dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{2}(x,y) dy}=\frac{\lim_{x \to a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{1}(x,y) dy}{\lim_{x \to a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_{2}(x,y) dy}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a}h_{1}(x,y) dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a} h_{2}(x,y) dy}$$

Comment: and...  $$=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a}\frac{h_{1}(x,y)}{h_{2}(x,y)} h_{2} (x,y) dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a} h_{2}(x,y) dy}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a}h_{2} (x,y) dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a} h_{2}(x,y) dy}=1$$, it makes sense for you?